# Using Linq in VB.NET to verify result set is NULL

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to validate wether or not two matching columns exists using Linq/VB.NET

I believe that assuming a null result set is being returned the 'Count' value should also be null, correct?

Below is the code;

```
    Dim crewNumEntered = crewNumInput.Text
    Dim crewLeaderNumEntered = crewLeaderNumInput.Text
    Dim crewNumUnique As Boolean = False

    Using db As New DbClassDataContext
        Dim Count = (From a In db.WarrantyPercents Where a.CrewLeaderNum = crewLeaderNumEntered And a.CrewNum = crewNumEntered Select a.WarrantyPercentsId).ToList
        If Count Is Nothing Then
            crewNumUnique = True
        Else
            'throw error
        End If
    End Using
```

The end result is I only want to perform an action (code not shown) if crewNumUnique == true.

But even when the result set should be null, this code is continuing to fill 'something' with Count.

What can I do to fix this?

EDIT: I just realized the value of count isn't null but instead returning the string 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'. Now I have no clue what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query will return a result set even when no matching rows are found.

The below sets crewNumUnique to True if there is exactly 1 result. If instead you want to set crewNumUnique to True when there are no results, use 0 in place of 1.

```
Dim result = From a In db.WarrantyPercents Where a.CrewLeaderNum = crewLeaderNumEntered And a.CrewNum = crewNumEntered
Dim count As Integer = result.Count
If count = 1 Then
   crewNumUnique = True
Else
   'throw Error
End If
```

Comment: That is still hitting the crewNumUnique = True.

Comment: Sorry, but the resultset is null. Maybe I am not asking the question right. If the resultset is null only then do I want crewNumUnique to be true.

Comment: Okay, I must have been doing something wrong because I restarted the project and now it is working correctly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Greg what do you recommend for a name instead?

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `ToList` .. it can never be null.

You should check its length.

```
If Count.Count = 0 Then

crewNumUnique = True

Else

End If
```